# Are there any limitations on input type="file" when added via javascript?

Tags: javascript

Are there any limitations on input type="file" when added via javascript?
Are there any security concerns?

Comment: No, because JavaScript cannot set the "value" property. All websites driven by template systems like React add `<input type=file>` things to their DOMs.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, But I'm having issues with input type="file" element added via javascript. It's not passing data to next page via POST. Here is the link to the question that I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832733/input-type-file-data-empty-when-posted It would be great if you can check what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Right: you **cannot** set the "value" attribute of a "file" `<input>`.  You can add the element, but the browser will ignore any attempts to set the value.

Comment: @Pointy But I'm not setting value attribute. I'm just adding input type="file" element in DOM via javascript.

Comment: Well then there should be no problem at all; it's a perfectly OK thing to do. You didn't post a single bit of code to help anybody understand the problem, so you probably won't get much help from this question.

Comment: @Pointy I've posted my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832733/input-type-file-data-empty-when-posted But no one is answering.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's none, security will always be on your server on how you handle those requests after posting it through ajax or form

Comment: I'm posting it via Form but it's not passing data. The $_FILES array shows empty.

Comment: do you put this in your form , enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: Yes. I've put it but still no luck. I've posted my code in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832733/input-type-file-data-empty-when-posted Could you please check what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you put a default value of it

Comment: No. Below is my javascript code
    `var typ = document.getElementById('panDamType').value;
    var par = document.getElementById('shwChoos');
    var cnt =  par.childElementCount;
    //create elements
    var elm1 = document.createElement('div');
    elm1.setAttribute('class', 'row');

    var elm2 = document.createElement('input');
    elm2.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    elm2.setAttribute('name', 'mtu');
    elm2.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    elm1.appendChild(elm2);
    par.appendChild(elm1);
    par.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));`

Comment: don't you use jquery for it ? to handle it in an easy way